# How to send an image as part of JSON payload in Flask

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to send an image in the JSON request payload and save it in DB. First, I'm encoding my data using base64 then sending it in the payload as shown below.

```
data_param = request.get_json(force=True)
    data = Serializer(data_param).is_valid()

    if len(data):

        image_file = data['attachment'] if data['attachment'] else ""
        if image_file:
             with open(image_file, "rb") as f:
                 im_bytes = f.read()
             im_b64 = base64.b64encode(im_bytes).decode("utf8")

        my_data = SampleModel(
             data1=my_data ['data1'],
             data2=my_data['data2'],
             attachment= im_b64,
             created_on=my_data['createdOn'],
             created_by=my_data['createdBy']
         )

        SampleModel.save_db(my_data)
        result = survey_data.to_string()
```

`save_db` and `to_string` functions are already created in the model file. I've only pasted the controller file.

Is this a correct approch to save in db? If not, then How should I proceed?

Comment: I see no problem with this - unless you don't actually want to persist the file in the db? You could alternatively just keep a filename or path in the database, and keep the file on disk instead, but this seems to be a design decision on your part.

Comment: Actually I want to save the image in db and then use it later if needed.

Comment: then I think this is the right approach. Do you get an error?